# NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) when object is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

My app consists in a form via which you can enter a word, submit, and then the controller will create a `Word` object with the word itself, and the definition and an example fetched via JSON from an API.

This is the conflicting line:

```
def create
  @word = Word.new(word_params)

  url = "http://api.pearson.com/v2/dictionaries/entries?headword=#{@word.word_name}"

  Rails.logger.info url
  uri = URI(url)
  Rails.logger.info uri
  response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  Rails.logger.info response
  result = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response)
  Rails.logger.info result

  @word.definition = result[0]["results"][0]["senses"][0]["definition"][0]
  @word.example = result[0]["results"][0]["senses"][0]["translation"][0]["example"][0]["text"]
  @word.save
  redirect_to @word
end
```

And here comes the error line:

```
@word.definition = result[0]["results"][0]["senses"][0]["definition"][0]

FATAL -- :NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

So I assumed that `result` was `nil`. So I logged it out but the result is exactly as expected [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK9iA.png)

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use result["results"] instead of result[0]["results"]

```
@word.definition = result["results"][0]["senses"][0]["definition"][0]
```